# NoNullAllowedException was handled in btnSave_Click

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

1. NoNullAllowedException was handled in btnSave_Click Event
2. I have four column DealerId, Name, Address, Phoneno in SQL 2005
3. If i click on Save Button i get this ERROR: **Column 'DealerID' does not allow nulls**

[image]

Error Message Image:

[image]

```
    public partial class frmDealerForm : Form
    {
    DataTable t;
    DataRow r;

    public frmDealerForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    } 

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t = kalliskaBillingDataSet.Tables["DealerDetail"];
        r = t.NewRow();
        r[0] = txtdealerID.Text;
        r[1] = txtname.Text;
        r[2] = txtaddress.Text;
        r[3] = txtphoneno.Text;
     //Column 'DealerID' does not allow nulls//
        t.Rows.Add(r);
        dealerDetailTableAdapter.Update(kalliskaBillingDataSet);
        txtdealerID.Text = System.Convert.ToString(r[0]);
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved", "DealerDetail", MessageBoxButtons.OK,  MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }
 }
```

Comment: use a break point to debug.seems you are not passing any value for dealerid.check whether all values for row is inserted.

Comment: Use the debugger if you have an IDE. The error message is pretty simple, you aren't giving a value for DealerID. Is this column an identity column in the database? Does it or should it accept `NULL`s?

Comment: The name and dealerId go in the same cell `r[0]` ?

Comment: yes i changed that V4Vendetta

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the following code instead:

```
    r[0] = txtdealerID.Text ?? String.Empty;
    r[1] = txtname.Text ?? String.Empty;
    r[2] = txtaddress.Text ?? String.Empty;
    r[3] = txtphoneno.Text ?? String.Empty;
```

That would make sure it's not null.

Also, make sure that the indexes is right. 0,0,1,2 seems wrong.

Also, if you use ORM (Linq to SQL, Entity Framework), make sure it's updated.

Answer (score 0):

On your Datatable,the DealerId column is set with the property

`DealerId.AllowDBNull = False`.Which is why you are getting that error.

You are probably passing a null value for r[0],which you cannot do when the above property is set.